# Django How to pass object id via form action?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm still having problems passing an object's id in the url of a form.

adjust.html

```
<form action="{% url 'classroom:deleteblock' classroom.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

models.py

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
    COURSE_NAME = (
        ('MA8', 'Math 8'),
        ('SC10', 'Science 10'),
        ('PH11', 'Physics 11'),
        ('PH12', 'Physics 12'),
    )
    BLOCK_NUMBER = (
        ('11', 'Block 1-1'),
        ('12', 'Block 1-2'),
        ('13', 'Block 1-3'),
        ('14', 'Block 1-4'),
        ('21', 'Block 2-1'),
        ('22', 'Block 2-2'),
        ('23', 'Block 2-3'),
        ('24', 'Block 2-4'),
    )
    class_list = models.TextField()
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=COURSE_NAME)
    course_block = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=BLOCK_NUMBER)
    group_size = models.IntegerField(default=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_course_block_display()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Classroom, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # overrides the default save function to parse the class list
        studentList = []
        studentList = self.class_list.split('\n')
        print (studentList)
        for line in studentList:
            line = line.strip('\r')
            s = Student.objects.create(nickname = line, classroom = self)

class DeleteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Classroom
        fields = ['course_block']
```

views.py

```
class BlockDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Classroom

delete_block_view = BlockDeleteView.as_view()

def adjust(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DeleteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'classroom/adjust.html')
    else:
        form = DeleteForm()

    return render(request, 'classroom/adjust.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^submitted', views.submitted, name='submitted'),
    url(r'^classup/$', create_classroom_view, name='classroom'),
    url(r'^block/$', views.block, name='block'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[09-]+)/deleteblock/$', delete_block_view, name='deleteblock'),
    url(r'^adjust/$', views.adjust, name='adjust'),
    url(r'^random/$', list_random_view, name='random'),
]
```

So the idea is that adjust.html gives me a form with one choice drop down menu corresponding to course_block.  I choose the course, click submit, and hopefully I'm redirected to `classroom_form.html`.  The action of the form is to send the object pk to DeleteView which I think is supposed to delete the object.

Running as above, I get an error: `Reverse for 'deleteblock' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['classroom/(?P<pk>[09-]+)/deleteblock/$']`.  How do a correctly pass the action url to match `deleteblock`?

I guess I'll find out soon, but do I need a `get_url_success()` in my `BlockDeleteView`?

EDIT: I've also tried passing a query to the template in the context but have the same error.
views.py

```
def adjust(request):
    classroom = Classroom.objects.all().first()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DeleteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'classroom/adjust.html', {'form':form}, {'classroom':classroom})
    else:
        form = DeleteForm()

    return render(request, 'classroom/adjust.html', {'form': form}, {'classroom': classroom})
```

Comment: classroom.id doesn't exist, you must pass that var in the context

Comment: I edited my code and I think I've passed the queryset to the template in the context, but I get the same error.  I'm not clear on how the context is passed.  The `return render(request, 'classroom/classroom_form.html', context)` is returned after the form validation, which doesn't seem right (but that's just my intuition).

Comment: return render(request, 'classroom/adjust.html', {'form': form}) is here, and in your url must be pk=classroom.id

Answer (score 2):

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/deleteblock/$', delete_block_view, name='deleteblock'),
```

`[0-9]+` not `[09-]+`, and you need a success_url or get_url_success() method in  BlockDeleteView

change your views.py:

```
class BlockDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Classroom
    slug_field = 'id'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('some_url')
    template_name = 'classroom/delete.html'
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/deleteblock/$', BlockDeleteView.as_view(), name='deleteblock'),
```

Comment: I've corrected the typo, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: so,what's the new error say?Exactly the same with before?

Comment: The error is `Reverse for 'deleteblock' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['classroom/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/deleteblock/$']`. Reading the [docs on url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url), I think the urls.py line should be `url(r'^deleteblock/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', delete_block_view, name='deleteblock')`. Either way, I get essentially the same error no matter what I've tried.

Comment: maybe something you don't post cause the error,and have you change what i wrote in views.py like：`class BlockDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Classroom
    slug_field = 'id'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('some_url')
    template_name = 'classroom/delete.html'`

Comment: you sure the error is cause by this line:`<form action="{% url 'classroom:deleteblock' classroom.id %}" method="post">`?

Comment: and make sure the classroom.id is exist by print it in template by `<p> {{ classroom.id}}</p>`

Comment: Thats a good idea, and classroom.id does not print anything. I dont know what to change in my view to get the variables in the template. Ive done it with overiding class based views but not with a defined view like ’def adjust(request)’

Comment: so the error is cause by no classroom object in template,if the adjust method in view server the adjust.html,change it's to `return render(request, 'classroom/adjust.html', {'form': form, 'classroom':classroom})`,and you need get the classroom object by you own logic in adjust method.

Comment: I really don't know how to do much more than I already have above in my views.py edit for `def adjust(request)`. I would think this passes the query `classroom=Classroom.objects.all()` to the template but it still doesn't print anything.

Comment: classroom is an object not queryset,simple to `classroom=Classroom.objects.all().first()`

Comment: Still doesn't print anything. It should, I checked it using the db api in a shell.

Comment: then check there is Classroom object in admin or db?

Comment: It is in the db.  I tried moving the return statement to above the `if request.method=='POST':`, commented out the form parts, and then the template printed classroom.

Comment: Edited. I didn't keep the return line above the if request.method=='POST"

Comment: is `return render(request, 'classroom/adjust.html', {'form': form, 'classroom': classroom})` not `return render(request, 'classroom/adjust.html', {'form': form}, {'classroom': classroom})`

Comment: You're correct.  That helps. I don't yet know if it solves all my problems but that it is definitely a correction.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be 0-9 and not 09- , used at the regex(regular expression) part of the url_mapping for the deleteblock at url_patterns.

Try this:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/deleteblock/$', delete_block_view, name='deleteblock')
```

Instead of this:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[09-]+)/deleteblock/$', delete_block_view, name='deleteblock')
```

Comment: I've corrected the typo, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`classroom.id` doesn't exist, you must pass that var in the context and in the url you have to be specific should be `{% url 'classroom:deleteblock' pk=classroom.id %}`

Comment: This gives a similar error: `Reverse for 'deleteblock' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['classroom/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/deleteblock/$']`

Comment: you have to pass the object classroom not the pk

Comment: I've tried every permutation I can think of: {% url 'classroom:deleteblock' pk %}, {.... pk=classroom.id %}, {.... classroom.id %}, {..... 'pk'=classroom.id %}, {... pk='classroom.id' %}.  I must be something else incorrectly.