# Django - Post to specific URL using form

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to post to a specific URL. The url has the scope of deleting a database row. The URL is composed by the address + the pk of the file selected in the form catched from a model.

*select_file_deletion.html*

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block content %}
<!--Here the number 2 in "/App/delete/2/" needs to be replaced with the pk of the file. The logic is working. -->
    <form action="/App/delete/{{ myfile.pk }}/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <h5>Please select one file at a time from the list below to delete it from the server.</h5>
        {% for myfile in filename %}
          <input type="checkbox" name="file_name" value="{{ myfile }}">
            <label>
                <a href="/media/{{ myfile }}">{{ myfile }}</a>
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ myfile.pk }}" name="pk">
            </label>
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

*Project urls.py*

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', FileDeleteView.as_view(), name='APIdelete')
```

*views.py*

```
class SelectFileDelView(TemplateView):
    """
    This view is used to select a file from the list of files in the server.
    After the selection, it will send the file to the server.
    The server will then delete the file.
    """
    template_name = 'select_file_deletion.html'
    parser_classes = FormParser
    queryset = FileModel.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        This function is used to render the list of files in the MEDIA_ROOT in the html template.
        """
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        media_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        myfiles = [f for f in listdir(media_path) if isfile(join(media_path, f))]
        context['filename'] = myfiles
        return context


class FileDeleteView(DeleteView):
    """
    This class contains the method to delete a file interacting directly with the API.
    DELETE requests are accepted.
    """
    # TODO: Fix, still not working
    model = FileModel
    fields = ['file']
    template_name = 'delete_success.html'
    success_url = '/delete_success/'
```

*App/urls.py*

```
# Url to select a file to be deleted and confirm the upload
url('filedelete/', SelectFileDelView.as_view(), name='file_delete'),
url('delete_success/', FileDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_success')
```

**ERROR**: the request URL row is not catching the address including the pk, not replacing the variable with the pk of the selected file.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/App/delete//
Using the URLconf defined in DjangoRestDeepLearning.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^App/ ^predict/$ [name='APIpredict']
^App/ ^upload/$ [name='APIupload']
^App/ ^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$ [name='APIdelete']
filedelete/ [name='file_delete']
delete_success/ [name='delete_success']
The current path, App/delete//, didn't match any of these.
```

**Question I checked before opening this one without solving the issue:**

1) [Delete object with form in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547018/delete-object-with-form-in-django)

2) [Django How to pass object id via form action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046439/django-how-to-pass-object-id-via-form-action)

Comment: I don't understand why you say "The logic is working". What is working, and what isn't?

Comment: Hi, sorry for missing clarity here. Image you have an object in the database with pk=2. If you make a post request using as URL action "/App/delete/2/" the row will be successfully deleted. What I want is that the 2 above becomes dynamic, catching the pk of the file selected by the user in the form.

Comment: But you can't do that (or at least not without JavaScript). The URL tag is evaluated at render time, not when you select something. You should remove that parameter from the URL and get it from the POST data.

Comment: You mean writing a function with a request.GET("file", pk) inside the view, right?

Comment: Well, in this case `request.POST["file_name"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you have the myfile.pk in your template.
The url in your form action isnt working as the pk is missing. Replace the action of the form with this:

```
   <form action="{% url 'APIdelete' pk=myfile.pk %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Hi, already tried this solution and, when I use it, I get "NoReverseMatch at /filedelete/
Reverse for 'APIdelete' not found. 'APIdelete' is not a valid view function or pattern name."